# Selenium: Python: How to use the '\' character in a string file-path

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have a question regarding how to properly use a '\' when denoting a filepath in Selenium Python. Here is the code snippet i'm using:

```
uploadElem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#mediaFile")
uploadElem.send_keys("C:\SVN\test_suites\aePortal_ui\Resources\QATAE0000001289-001_hr.pdf")
```

while the first \S part of the filepath aren't an issue, both \t & \a seem to be pre-built operations in Python. How could I still use the file path without invoking those Python operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape a `\` by placing another `\` in front of it, e.g.: `C:\\SVN\\test''...`

Alternatively, put an `r` before the string to declare the string 'raw' (i.e. ignore all escape characters): `path = r'C:\SVN\test_suites\...\`

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your backslashes, i.e:

```
uploadElem.send_keys("C:\\SVN\\test_suites\\aePortal_ui\\Resources\\QATAE0000001289-001_hr.pdf")
```

The fact that no damage is done by `\S` specifically, does not make escaping it wrong.